# Executing new database queries while looping through a query result

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a relatively heavy MySQL select query that returns ca 150 MB of data in 25.000 rows. Looping through the whole dataset and performing the required operations, takes about 45 minutes.

For a few of the records (less than 10) I need to perform another lookup in the same database.

If I write my Python 3 code like this:

```python
con = mysql.connection.connect( host='...', user='...', password='...', database='...' )
cursor = con.cursor( dictionary=True, buffered=True )

cursor.execute('SELECT ...')
for row in cursor:
  # processing data ...
  if row['...'] == ...:
    cursor2 = con.cursor()
    cursor2.execute('SELECT ...')
    some_var = cursor2.fetch_one()[0]
  # more processing...
```

Then, at the second execution of `cursor2`, I get:

```
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

If I initialize `cursor2` before the loop:

```python
con = mysql.connection.connect( host='...', user='...', password='...', database='...' )
cursor = con.cursor( dictionary=True, buffered=True )
cursor2 = con.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT ...')
for row in cursor:
  # processing data ...
  if row['...'] == ...:
    cursor2.execute('SELECT ...')
    some_var = cursor2.fetch_one()[0]
  # more processing...
```

Then, at the second execution I get:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I'm not really sure if these errors are caused by time-outs, or if it is caused by my wrong handling of multiple cursors.

If it helps, these are the timeout settings of my database:

connect_timeout 10
deadlock_timeout_long   50000000
deadlock_timeout_short  10000
delayed_insert_timeout  300
idle_readonly_transaction_timeout   0
idle_transaction_timeout    0
idle_write_transaction_timeout  0
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
interactive_timeout 28800
lock_wait_timeout   86400
net_read_timeout    30
net_write_timeout   60
rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout    10000
rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout   5
slave_net_timeout   60
thread_pool_idle_timeout    60
wait_timeout    420

How should I write this code instead? This is only my second Python script, so please formulate any help at a beginners level.

Comment: Try creating a second connection for cursor2. The first cursor is open so it may be blocking the connection.

Comment: @Mike67 creating a new connection for the second cursor doesn't help either. With the second example, I am getting the exact same error message, and with the first example (creating a new connection for ever query) I get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out connections are behaving a bit different from what I was expecting. The comment from @Mike67 pointed in the right direction, I just missing some of the details. The solution is to create and destroy a new connection every time a new query is needed.

```py
con = mysql.connection.connect( host='...', user='...', password='...', database='...' )
cursor = con.cursor( dictionary=True, buffered=True )

cursor.execute('SELECT ...')
for row in cursor:
  # processing data ...
  if row['...'] == ...:
    con2 = mysql.connection.connect( host='...', user='...', password='...', database='...' )
    cursor2 = con2.cursor()
    cursor2.execute('SELECT ...')
    some_var = cursor2.fetch_one()[0]
    cursor2.close()
    con2.close()
  # more processing...
```

I have a feeling there must be a more efficient way to do this, but this works.